# Can’t get TLSv1.3 to work with nginx 1.14.0 and OpenSSL 1.1.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: nginx, openssl, tls

I’m going nuts here to trying to figure out how to enable TLSv1.3 on my nginx server.

Based on my research, my setup *should* support it:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

# uname -a
Linux server 5.3.0-28-generic #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 06:14:09 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
TLS SNI support enabled
...

# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018

# dpkg -s openssl | grep Version
Version: 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.5
```

I have included the TLSv1.3 protocol and even (tho’ I understand it is optional) specifically listed the TLSv1.3 ciphers in my nginx config:

```
...
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256;
ssl_ecdh_curve X25519:secp384r1;
...
```

But I can’t connect to the server using TLSv1.3, whether by browser (which *can* connect to other websites via TLSv1.3) or `curl`:

```
# curl -I -v --tlsv1.3 --tls-max 1.3 https://mydomain.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://mydomain.com/
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to mydomain.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

TLSv1.2 works fine.

What I am missing please?!

---

**EDIT**

Some additional troubleshooting information:

```
# openssl s_client -tls1_3 -connect mydomain.com:443
CONNECTED(00000005)
140179247497664:error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1528:SSL alert number 70
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 244 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Again, I have no issue when running this with TLSv1.2 as the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my issue. I had a default_server config also included in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`, which didn't have the TLSv1.3 flag in the ssl_protocols parameter (in fact, it didn't have a ssl_protocols parameter at all). This apparently caused the failure, even though my tests were run on hostnames that were served by different server blocks. Go figure!

Comment: Same here. Although default_server block had "ssl_reject_handshake on;" in it. Makes no sense, but TLSv1.3 works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried answering on other thread however for whatever reason I couldn't.

I tried your test on my own server(s) however I'm getting this:

```
curl -I -v --tlsv1.3 --tls-max 1.3 https://bw.domain.com
*   Trying 10.0.1.86:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to bw.domain.com (10.0.1.86) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=bw.domain.com
*  start date: Feb  3 16:54:01 2020 GMT
*  expire date: May  3 16:54:01 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "bw.domain.com" matched cert's "bw.domain.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: bw.domain.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.16.1
Server: nginx/1.16.1
< Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2020 15:23:50 GMT
Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2020 15:23:50 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 1373
Content-Length: 1373
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=600
Cache-Control: public, max-age=600
< Feature-Policy: accelerometer 'none'; ambient-light-sensor 'none'; autoplay 'none'; camera 'none'; encrypted-media 'none'; fullscreen 'none'; geolocation 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; microphone 'none'; midi 'none'; payment 'none'; picture-in-picture 'none'; sync-xhr 'self' https://haveibeenpwned.com https://twofactorauth.org; usb 'none'; vr 'none'
Feature-Policy: accelerometer 'none'; ambient-light-sensor 'none'; autoplay 'none'; camera 'none'; encrypted-media 'none'; fullscreen 'none'; geolocation 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; microphone 'none'; midi 'none'; payment 'none'; picture-in-picture 'none'; sync-xhr 'self' https://haveibeenpwned.com https://twofactorauth.org; usb 'none'; vr 'none'
< Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' chrome-extension://nngceckbapebfimnlniiiahkandclblb moz-extension://* ;
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' chrome-extension://nngceckbapebfimnlniiiahkandclblb moz-extension://* ;
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:

<
* Connection #0 to host bw.domain.com left intact
```

My reverse proxy is nginx but its configured with Mozilla intermediate.  Despite the intermediate ssl-params, the TLS1.3 handshake looks to be established.

```
# openssl version                      
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019

# nginx -V                             
nginx version: nginx/1.16.1
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
TLS SNI support enabled

# uname -a
Linux 5.4.15-arch1-1
```

I'm using the following nginx-ssl params

```
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;  # about 40000 sessions
ssl_session_tickets off;

# curl https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ffdhe2048.txt > /path/to/dhparam.pem
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem;

# intermediate configuration
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECD
SA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:
ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

# HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
#add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;

# OCSP stapling
#ssl_stapling on;
#ssl_stapling_verify on;

resolver 10.0.1.1;
```